# Error parsing JSON

Tags: objective-c, ios, json

Good evening!

I need some help to parse a JSON from Google Directions.
I have the following code to get the html_instructions value:

```
NSString *myRawJson = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                           [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-15.802737,-47.87963&destination=-15.851783,-47.954593&sensor=true"]];

    // Create a dictionary from the JSON string
    NSDictionary *results = [myRawJson JSONValue];

    NSArray *resultarr = [results objectForKey:@"routes"];
    NSString *string;
    //NSArray *subarray;

    for(NSDictionary *di in resultarr){
        NSLog(@"loop");
        NSDictionary *subdic = [[di objectForKey:@"legs"] objectForKey:@"steps"];
        string = [subdic objectForKey:@"html_instructions"];
        NSLog(@"%@",string);
    }
    (...)
```

When I run it, I get the following error

> -[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d9b3e0
>   2011-11-02 22:53:02.110 APSplitSample[1470:11603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d9b3e0'

Here's the JSON (can be seen complete running the url above):

```
{
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : -15.79760,
               "lng" : -47.879710
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : -15.874160,
               "lng" : -47.958310
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Dados cartográficos ©2011 MapLink",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "16,0 km",
                  "value" : 15989
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "16 minutos",
                  "value" : 945
               },
               "end_address" : "Estr. Epia - Candangolândia, Brasília - DF, Brasil",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : -15.851770,
                  "lng" : -47.95470
               },
               "start_address" : "Via de Ligação Se/ne - Brasília, DF, Brasil",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : -15.802960,
                  "lng" : -47.879710
               },
               "steps" : [
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,6 km",
                        "value" : 625
                     },
                     "duration" : {
                        "text" : "1 min",
                        "value" : 59
                     },
                     "end_location" : {
                        "lat" : -15.800940,
                        "lng" : -47.885150
                     },
                     "html_instructions" : "Siga na direção \u003cb\u003eoeste\u003c/b\u003e na \u003cb\u003eVia de Ligação Se/ne\u003c/b\u003e em direção à \u003cb\u003eVia Bs S Um\u003c/b\u003e",
                     "polyline" : {
                        "points" : "nom_BdofcHa@hB[rACRId@Kf@g@|BOl@AFKb@Kd@i@~BaArCKZiA`DKVCFGLCFKX"
                     },
                     "start_location" : {
                        "lat" : -15.802960,
                        "lng" : -47.879710
                     },
                     "travel_mode" : "DRIVING"
                  },
                  {
                     "distance" : {
                        "text" : "0,1 km",
                        "value" : 101
                     },
 (...)
```

Can someone help on it?!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI I hope use this code may be help to u

```
    NSDictionary *mainDict=[requeststring JSONValue];

    //NSLog(@"maindict values is %d",[mainDict count]);


    NSArray *routesArray=[mainDict objectForKey:@"routes"];

        if ([routesArray count]>0)
        {


    NSDictionary *routeDict=[routesArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *legsarray=[routeDict objectForKey:@"legs"];



    NSDictionary *legsdict=[legsarray objectAtIndex:0];







        NSDictionary *distDict=[legsdict objectForKey:@"distance"];

        NSString *distncestring=[distDict objectForKey:@"text"];

        NSDictionary *timeDict=[legsdict objectForKey:@"duration"];

        NSString *time=[timeDict objectForKey:@"text"];




    NSDictionary *startlatdict=[legsdict objectForKey:@"start_location"];
    float latt=[[startlatdict objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
    float long=[[startlatdict objectForKey:@"lng"] floatValue];






    NSArray *stepsarray=[legsdict objectForKey:@"steps"];

        for (int i=0; i<[stepsarray count]; i++)
        {

            NSDictionary *stepsdict=[stepsarray objectAtIndex:i];

            NSDictionary *endlattdict=[stepsdict objectForKey:@"end_location"];

            float lang1=[[endlattdict objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue];
            float long1=[[endlattdict objectForKey:@"lng"] floatValue];


NSString *instStr =[stepsdict objectForKey:@"html_instructions"];

        NSLog(@"html_instructions%@",instStr);




        }
```

}

this code help to u get all information for google map json data

Good Luck

Comment: Where do I get the class ASIFormDataRequest?

Comment: import ASIHttpRequest file into your project

Answer (score 1):

The result of:

```
[di objectForKey:@"legs"]
```

appears to be another array, not a dictionary. So when you add on

```
[[di objectForJet:@"legs"] objectForKey:@"steps"]
```

you are sending the objectForKey message to an NSArray.

Try something like this:

```
NSArray *legs = [di objectForKey@"legs];
for (NSDictionary *subdic in legs) {
    string = [subdic objectForKey:@"html_instructions"];
    NSLog(@"%@",string);
}
```